# R does not understand dates in a subset

Tags: r, date

I am having a small issue with my code, that I do not understand. I have been using R for many years now, but this is a new issue for me.

I have a dataframe with dates (sdata) and I want to see check to which row of another dataframe this corresponds (meteo), see example below:

with:

```
str(meteo)
'data.frame':   13880 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ station : int  22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 ...
 $ Date    : Date, format: "1981-01-01" "1981-01-02" "1981-01-03" "1981-01-04" ...
 $ minte   : num  0 -0.2 1 0.4 -5.5 -8.3 -13.1 -14.2 -3.6 -0.5 ...
 $ maxte   : num  4.5 6.4 6.3 0.7 -3.6 -4.1 -3 2 3 1.8 ...
 $ MeanTemp: num  2.2 3.1 3.6 0.6 -4.6 -6.2 -8 -6.1 -0.3 0.6 ...
 $ prec08  : num  2.8 0.2 12 3.1 8 0.6 0 0 1.6 0.8 ...
 $ glorad  : num  1.9 2.5 0.6 0.6 3.2 4.9 3.8 0.6 0.6 5.1 ...
 $ makkepot: num  0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.6 ...
 $ doy     : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

and

```
str(sdata)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Group.1      : int  1997 1998 1999 2000
 $ Sow          : Date, format: "1997-04-17" "1998-04-21" "1999-04-17" "2000-04-07"
 $ Emergence    : Date, format: "1997-05-06" "1998-05-02" "1999-04-29" "2000-04-22"
 $ FirstNode    : Date, format: "1997-06-11" "1998-05-31" "1999-05-31" "2000-05-22"
 $ FlagLeaf     : Date, format: "1997-06-16" "1998-06-15" "1999-06-15" "2000-05-30"
 $ Anthesis     : Date, format: NA NA NA NA
 $ Ripeness     : Date, format: "1997-07-27" "1998-07-29" "1999-08-02" "2000-07-25"
 $ Harvest      : Date, format: "1997-08-14" "1998-09-02" "1999-08-24" "2000-08-24"
 $ DOY_sow      : num  5951 6320 6681 7037
 $ DOY_emergence: num  19 11.2 12.2 15
 $ DOY_elong    : num  55 40 44 45
 $ DOY_flag     : num  60.5 55.6 59.6 53
 $ DOY_ant      : num  NaN NaN NaN NaN
 $ DOY_mat      : num  101.5 99.7 107 109
 $ DOY_har      : num  119 134 129 139
```

I am encountering the following issue:

```
Browse[2]> sdata$Ripeness[1]
[1] "1997-07-27"
Browse[2]> sdata$Ripeness[2]
[1] "1998-07-29"
Browse[2]> sdata$Ripeness[3]
[1] "1999-08-02"
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date==sdata$Ripeness[1])
integer(0)
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date==sdata$Ripeness[2])
integer(0)
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date==sdata$Ripeness[3])
[1] 6788
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date==sdata$Ripeness[4])
[1] 7146
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date=="1997-07-27")
[1] 6052
Browse[2]> which(meteo$Date=="1998-07-29")
[1] 6419

Browse[2]> str(sdata$Ripeness[1])
 Date[1:1], format: "1997-07-27"
Browse[2]> str(sdata$Ripeness[2])
 Date[1:1], format: "1998-07-29"
```

For some reason R does not like the first 2 occurences of sdata$Ripeness, has someone ever encountered such a problem? And if so, how to solve this?

Comment: Can you share `dput(sdata$Ripeness[1])` and `dput(meteo[6788, "Date"])`? Are they the same?

Comment: Don't compare dates (or datetimes) with characters. Use `meteo$Date == as.Date("1997-07-27")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason R decided to add a time to the date (that is only visible when you look at the POSIXct:

```
Browse[2]> as.POSIXct(sdata$Ripeness)
[1] "1997-07-27 14:00:00 CEST" "1998-07-29 18:00:00 CEST" "1999-08-02 02:00:00 CEST" "2000-07-25 02:00:00 CEST"
```

So the work around is:

```
as.Date(as.character(sdata$Ripeness))
```

Comment: The reason is probably in how you create these dates. Internally, `Date` objects are just the number of dates since the origin. This number does not need to be full days, e.g., `x <- as.Date(20.1, origin = "2019-07-01"); as.POSIXct(x)`. You do not need to coerce to character. You can use `trunc` or `round` (depending how you want to handle the partial days).